# Face Recognizer opencv class for android

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision, android-camera, face-recognition

I am trying to build a face recognition application for Android. According to this link:

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html

there is a class called FaceRecognizer that is a good abstraction layer for face recognition functionality.

At this link: http://docs.opencv.org/ it says that this FaceRecognizer class is in the "contrib" folder. However, when I download OpenCV for Android, and import it to my Eclipse workspace, I don't see the "contrib" folder. Hence, I am not able to go ahead with this app.

Do you know if the FaceRecognizer class is available for OpenCV for Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenCV4Android bindings are generated by a wrapper generator script, so not the entire OpenCV library is supported yet. I've talked to Kirill Kornyakov, one of the OpenCV4Android maintainers, a while ago and here's what he said on FaceRecognizer for OpenCV4Android:

> I've decided to double check with Andrey Pavlenko, who is the private
>   developer of the Java bindings for OpenCV. He said that for the full
>   support he needs to fix a couple of things, to help wrapper generator
>   script to understand some data types. This is not specific for
>   FaceRecognizer, this is a general and quite important task in our
>   Roadmap. So, hopefully this will be finished before the 2.4.3 which is
>   coming ~ November 1st. We're also getting a lot of questions about
>   FaceRec on Android, and it will be one of our priorities for the next
>   release.

Comment: By "next release" do you mean the release on November 1st?

Comment: Yes. Feel free to ask on http://answers.opencv.org, if it isn't included in the next release and refer to this post.